# How to debug my JavaScript dropdown list?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to get the code to select what's in the dropdown list and display an image with some text.This is what I got so far. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

```
<form action="">
 
  <select id="cars">
    <option value="1" href="https://i.imgur.com/sXWdODh.jpg">Ford Mustang</option>
    <option value="2">Mercedes E400</option>
    <option value="3">Chevy Camaro SS</option>
    <option value="4">Honda Civic</option>
    <option value="5">Tesla Model X</option>
  </select>
</form>

<br>
<button type="button" onclick="showcars()">Submit</button>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Reset</button>


   <script>
        function showcars(){
      
    var select = document.getElementById("cars");
      
    var carName = select.value;
      
    document.write(carame);
}
        </script>
<script>
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("2").value = "honda";
}
  document.getElementById("1").src = "fordmustang";

</script>




</body>
</center>    
<br>
<br>
</html>
```

Comment: You have a typo: `document.write(carame);` should be `document.write(carName);` You also don't have any elements with an id of 1 o 2.

Answer (score 1):

It would be much easier to help if you were more specific about what you wanted to achieve, and what specifically isn't happening that should be.

That said, there are a couple typos in your code that could be causing you problems.

```
document.write(carame);
```

should be

```
document.write(carName);
```

And

```
document.getElementById("1").src = "fordmustang";
```

should be inside myFunction(), so move it up so it's inside the closing bracket.

That, at least, allows the code to run without errors.